# jQuery User Interface - Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

i have a little problem. I am integrating the autocomplete into the search in WordPress. The form works in any part of the site. If I run it through the searchform.php it does not work, why? I have pasted all this form including the script directly into the searchform file

[image]

In this example the working form inserted manually into the container

Comment: hi and welcome to stackoverflow, please dont provide your code as a screenshot, if you want to find someone, who solves your issue.

Comment: I made an edit request and added the `jquery` tag... because I came here for JavaScript D: (you may also want to add PHP) And like another comment sad: Please provide you're code in a code block... https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting